# Angular re-fetch data after parameter change GET request

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, http

How to re-fetch data after parameter change from:
oglas/1 to oglas/2 by click, so when put URL and than click ENTER everything works, but when click on oglas/2 button when oglas/1 is rendered URL changes to oglas/2 but data is from oglas/1?

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Post } from "../post.model";
import { ServerService } from "../server.service";

@Component({
  selector: "post",
  templateUrl: "./post.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post.component.css"]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private serverService: ServerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPost();
  }

  getPost(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.serverService.getPosts(id).subscribe(post => (this.post = post));
  }
}
```

Service

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Post } from "./post.model";
import { User } from "./user.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ServerService {
  usersUrl = "http://localhost:3000/users";
  postsUrl = "http://localhost:3000/posts";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts(id: number | string): Observable<Post[]> {
    const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(url);
  }

  getUser(id: number | string): Observable<User[]> {
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the routing module where you defined app routing?

Comment: App routing module https://codeshare.io/adb86B @MuhammadFaisal

Comment: You must use the following line of code if you want to refetch data on the same URL

Comment: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})]

Comment: not working, it's same but just got hash in front

Comment: remove useHash:true

Comment: Can you show the running example on stackblitz?

Comment: Please refer to URL for more details https://blog.angularindepth.com/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e

Comment: Have a read of my article on Angular state management with my library ngx-RxCache https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
  // do something with the query params
 });
 this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
  this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id);
 }); ..........this code works just it's very slow

Answer (score 1):

Since your are making an API call for data in `ngOnInit()`, requested data may not be available by the time your component loads. And Angular might be reusing the same instance of the component, making `ngOnInit()` to be called only once.

You can use Angular Resolvers to ensure that you have the required data before loading the component.

1) Create a route resolver to fetch the required data before loading the route.

**PostDataResolver.ts:**

```
// ... imports

@Injectable()
export class PostDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {

 constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}

 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

   const id = route.paramMap.get('id');

   return this.serverService.getPosts(id);
 }
}
```

2) Add this resolver to your routing module:

```
{ path: "oglas/:id", component: PostComponent, resolve: { postData: PostDataResolver }}
```

3) Then access the resolved data in your component.

**PostComponent.ts:**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private serverService: ServerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.post = this.route.snapshot.data.postData;
  }
}
```

This ensures that you have the latest and appropriate data before the component loads.

Comment: Still nothing...This is one component just want to re-render new data again after button click @Nikhil thank you for your effort

Comment: this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => { // do something with the query params }); this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => { this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id); }); ..........this code works just it's very slow

Comment: I don't see this code posted. Looks like another issue. I should be able to help if you can single out the current problem, and report what didn't work with my solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would post it....There is no issue everything renders fine, but want to fetch new data from database when click sidebar button to the same component...URL changes but data not...this code works but it is very slow https://codeshare.io/amvrzj @Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Post } from "../post.model";
import { ServerService } from "../server.service";

@Component({
  selector: "post",
  templateUrl: "./post.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post.component.css"]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post[];
  id: number;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private serverService: ServerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = parseInt(params.get("id"));
      this.getPost(this.id);
    });
  }

  getPost(id: number): void {
    this.serverService.getPosts(id).subscribe(post => (this.post = post));
  }
}
```

This code re-fetch data to a component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = parseInt(params.get("id"));
      this.getPost(this.id);
    });
  }
```

Thank you all for your effort!